# React functional component not redering inside parent functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

For reference, I have this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bdqzxn?file=index.tsx) . You can check output there not working.

I have one `TodoList Line Item` component and I want to render `LineItem` component inside of `TodoListLineItem` component. I am Using react with functional components and hooks with typescript.

```
<div className="container">
      <TodoForm />
      <TodoListLineItem>
          <LineItem />
      </TodoListLineItem>
</div>
```

As, shown above when i am trying to put `<LineItem />` component inside of `<TodoListLineItem>`  then, LineItem component is not rendering inside of parent component.

My Question is how to render LineItem component inside of parent TodoListLineItem component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LineItem` component is a child of `TodoListLineItem` component. You need to render `LineItem` component inside `TodoListLineItem` component in order to render `LineItem` component.

When you nest a component like `LineItem` is nested inside `TodoListLineItem` component, that nested component is passed as a prop to the surrounding component and is accessible inside the surrounding component using `children` property on the `props` object.

`props.children` will be an array that contains all the children components of
`TodoListLineItem` component. You can render all the children of `TodoListLineItem` by rendering `props.children` in `TodoListLineItem` component

```
const TodoListLineItem: React.FC = (props) =>{
   const [close, setClose] = useState(false);

   return (
     <div>
       <label className="line-item-header"> All Todo List items </label>
       { props.children }       {/* render all the children of TodoListLineItem */}
     </div>
   );
}
```

#### Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-asvv7x

You can learn about `props.children` on [React Docs - Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: Then how can we pass custom state from `<TodoListLineItem customState={'state'} >` and getting data of state inside of component ?

Comment: You mean you want to pass state from `TodoListLineItem` component to `LineItem` component?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that.

Comment: For that, you need to render `LineItem` components inside `TodoListLineItem` component. If there are more than one `LineItem` components, you can pass an array as a prop to `TodoListLineItem` component and inside the `TodoListLineItem` component, you can use `.map()` function to iterate over the array and render one or more `ListItem` components, passing in the data as props that you want to pass to `LineItem` component.

Comment: Okay. but, `<TodoListLineItem ch={s}>  <LineItem />  </TodoListLineItem>` here, how can we get state of ch inside `<LineItem>`

Comment: You can pass it as a prop to `LineItem`: `<LineItem ch={s} />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219328/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-yousaf).